# Cannot read Exported xls file in c#

Tags: c#

First I was export gridviewdata to excel format then i was import the same export excel wthout save the error occurred(External table is not in the expected format)
.but i was saveas the same file it worked.

below code to be used for export gridview to excel

```
    Response.Clear();
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=FileName.xls");
    Response.Charset = "";
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.xls";

    System.IO.StringWriter stringWrite = new System.IO.StringWriter();
    System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter htmlWrite = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWrite);

    gvopp.RenderControl(htmlWrite);
    Response.Write(stringWrite.ToString());
    Response.End();
```

Import Excel file below code to be used

```
   if (Extension == ".xls")
    {
        conStr = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + FilePath +
                    ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=No;IMEX=1\"";
    }
    else if (Extension == ".xlsx")
    {

        conStr = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source="+FilePath+";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1\";";
    }


    conStr = String.Format(conStr, FilePath, isHDR);

    OleDbConnection connExcel = new OleDbConnection(conStr);

    OleDbCommand cmdExcel = new OleDbCommand();

    OleDbDataAdapter oda = new OleDbDataAdapter();

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    DataTable dtid = new DataTable();

    cmdExcel.Connection = connExcel;

    //Get the name of First Sheet

  connExcel.Open();

    DataTable dtExcelSchema;

    dtExcelSchema = connExcel.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);

    string SheetName = dtExcelSchema.Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
    connExcel.Close();`
```

Please solve this pblm.

Comment: Your export is in the end a HTML file, that XLS can read, but it stays a HTML file, your reader expects an XLS file, so either fix your export to also use the oledb, or fix your reader to read html ;)

Comment: thks sir,but i was save that excel file i got error. There is no row at position 0 plz solve my pblm sir..

Comment: In all honesty, i hardly understand what you are talking about, there is no info about where your error is located, or even what you are trying to do, do your best, to update your question in such a way that anyone can understand your question, and not just you...